# Bash-shell after matching one file from another file, print out both match content and not match content at one time

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

```
cat fiel1.txt
cheng 600
huang 500
pan 400
yin 300

cat file2.txt
600 a
300 c
```

After I execute

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($2 in a){print $1,$2,a[$2]}' f2.txt f1.txt
```

The result as below:

```
cheng 600 a
yin 300 c
```

and I also want to print the column that not in array a . like below:

```
cheng 600 a
huang 500
pan 400
yin 300 c
```

How can I get the result. I try command like below:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($2 in a){print $1,$2,a[$2]}($2 not in a){print $1,$2,a[$2]}' f2.txt f1.txt
```

But it was failed.

Comment: yes, I think the fail reason may be relevant with programmer, sorry for not declare it clearly. Now I know How to get the result i expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {if($2 in a)print $1,$2,a[$2]; else print $1,$2}' f2.txt f1.txt
cheng 600 a
huang 500
pan 400
yin 300 c
```

#### Discussion

You had:

```
($2 in a){print $1,$2,a[$2]}
```

This prints only if `$2` is in `a`.  We replaced that with:

```
if($2 in a)print $1,$2,a[$2]; else print $1,$2
```

This prints `$1,$2,a[$2]` is `$2` is in `a`.  Otherwise, it just prints `$1,$2`.

#### Simpler version

If you mind some extraneous trailing blanks, we can use the still simpler:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1,$2,a[$2]}' f2.txt f1.txt
cheng 600 a
huang 500 
pan 400 
yin 300 c
```

Comment: yes. it works. and could you point out what's wrong with `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($2 in a){print $1,$2,a[$2]}($2 not in a){print $1,$2,a[$2]}' f2.txt f1.txt`, this my caused by grammar issue.

Comment: @huangcheng Glad it worked for you.  As for that command, replace `($2 not in a)` with `!($2 in a)`.  In awk, unlike say python, `!` is logical negation.